# TravisCI上でPython3.7で`poetry install`を実行すると、`importlib-metadata`のインストールで失敗します。

Tags: python, travis-ci, poetry

## 環境

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Python3.7.7
- pip 20.1
- poetry 1.1.13

## やりたいこと

TravisCI上で、Python3.7から3.10のテストを実施したいです。

## 問題

Python3.7の環境では、`poetry install`で以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
16.45s$ travis_retry poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file
Package operations: 60 installs, 10 updates, 0 removals
  • Installing typing-extensions (4.2.0): Pending...
  • Updating zipp (3.1.0 -> 3.8.0): Pending...
• Updating zipp (3.1.0 -> 3.8.0): Pending...
• Installing typing-extensions (4.2.0): Failed
  • Updating zipp (3.1.0 -> 3.8.0): Pending...
  • Updating zipp (3.1.0 -> 3.8.0): Pending...
EnvCommandError
  • Updating zipp (3.1.0 -> 3.8.0): Pending...
  • Updating zipp (3.1.0 -> 3.8.0): Pending...
Command ['/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.7/bin/python', '-W', 'ignore', '-'] errored with the following return code 1, and output: 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 871, in <module>
    File "<stdin>", line 871, in <listcomp>
    File "<stdin>", line 860, in sys_tags
    File "<stdin>", line 277, in cpython_tags
    File "<stdin>", line 785, in _linux_platforms
  AttributeError: module 'distutils' has no attribute 'util'
  input was : # This file is dual licensed under the terms of the Apache License, Version
  # 2.0, and the BSD License. See the LICENSE file in the root of this repository
  # for complete details.
  
  from __future__ import absolute_import
  
  import distutils.util
```

https://app.travis-ci.com/github/kurusugawa-computer/annofab-api-python-client/jobs/575582381#L292-L320

## 質問

このエラーは何を意味していて、どのように解決すればよいでしょうか？

## 補足

### pip install poetryでエラー発生

`pip install poetry`コマンドで、以下のエラーが発生していました。これが関係しているのかもしれません。

```
$ pip install poetry
...

Collecting pycparser
  Using cached pycparser-2.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
ERROR: keyring 23.6.0 has requirement importlib-metadata>=3.6; python_version < "3.10", but you'll have importlib-metadata 1.6.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: poetry-core 1.0.8 has requirement importlib-metadata<2.0.0,>=1.7.0; python_version >= "2.7" and python_version < "2.8" or python_version >= "3.5" and python_version < "3.8", but you'll have importlib-metadata 1.6.0 which is incompatible.
```

https://app.travis-ci.com/github/kurusugawa-computer/annofab-api-python-client/jobs/575582381#L274-L278

追記：keyring22.3.0を先にインストールすれば、このエラーは発生しなくなることは確認しました。
[Python3.7で"pip install poetry"を実行すると、"importlib-metadata"で依存性競合のエラーが発生します。なぜ、pipは依存性をうまい具合に解決してくれないのでしょうか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/89904/)

### ローカル環境では成功する

ローカル環境でPython3.7.7を作成して`poetry install`を実行したら、エラーは発生しませんでした。

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.7

$ pip --version
pip 19.2.3 from /home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

$ poetry --version
Poetry version 1.1.13
```

### 以前のビルド結果

以前はPython3.7で`poetry install`が成功していました。
https://app.travis-ci.com/github/kurusugawa-computer/annofab-api-python-client/jobs/572311461

### travis.yaml

```
version: ~> 1.0
dist: focal
language: python
python:
  - "3.7"
  - "3.8"
  - "3.9"
  - "3.10"
install:
  - pip install poetry
  - travis_retry poetry install
env:
  - PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100

cache: pip
```

### pyproject.toml

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.7"
requests = "*"
python-dateutil = "*"
backoff="*"
dataclasses-json="*"
more-itertools = "*"


[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "*"
pytest-xdist = "*"
pytest-cov = "*"
isort = "*"
autoflake = "*"
black = "*"
flake8 = "*"
mypy = "*"
pylint = "*"
sphinx = "*"
docutils = "*"
pydata-sphinx-theme = "*"
types-requests = "*"
types-python-dateutil = "*"
types-dataclasses = { version = "*", python = "<3.7" }
ipython = "*"
jedi = "<0.18"
```

Comment: keyringのバージョンが問題なのかもしれない